# What is the item of 'connection strings' for on azure? And how could I add it?

Tags: azure

Here is the picture.
http://www.dotup.org/uploda/www.dotup.org3258537.jpg

I have an connection string to connect to the SQL Server Database on the web.config of my website.
Would this item on the azure portal bring benefits to me?

Comment: Can you repost your picure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the connection string for items in the Linked Resources section of the portal for the website - which currently only supports SQL Database (and not Windows Azure Storage, for example). The following is [documented](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/):

> Connections Strings – View connection strings for linked resources.
>   For .NET sites, these connection strings will be injected into your
>   .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding
>   existing entries where the key equals the linked database name. For
>   PHP and Node sites these settings will be available as environment
>   variables at runtime.
>
> Note Connection strings are created when you link a database resource
>   to a website and are read only when viewed on the configuration
>   management page.